# CCA: Accessing Google APIs on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I have made a Chrome cca app that I want to run on Android, iOS, and Chrome.  I have done all of my testing in Chrome, because it's the fastest to re-build and run.

I am using Google APIs using the `identity` feature of Chrome Apps, and I have my `client_id` in the `manifest.json`.  When running as a Chrome app, all of my requests with `gapi.client.request` work perfectly.  However when I run on Android, they return a 403 `Acess Not Configured` error.  This doesn't happy with the initial request to authorize, but only with subsequent requests to get information.  In this case, I am using the Google Calendar API.

Is there something I need to know about deploying to Android with `identity`?  Do I need a separate `client_id`?

Edit: I have found and followed the instructions for Android at https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/tree/master/chrome-cordova/plugins/chrome.identity, it is still giving the same error (5 mins after adding client_id to APIs console).

Comment: Seems that just waiting ~18 hours did the trick.  I guess the Google APIs console takes a while to update.

Comment: You should probably answer the question with that to close it; it seems reasonably valuable to keep the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that just waiting ~18 hours did the trick. I guess the Google APIs console takes a while to update.